# Get Project Users (beta) Down?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

It appears that there is an issue with the Get Project Users endpoint. It has been working fine for a long time, but now is returning a 500 Internal Server error with every request I have tried.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/
I am not using any of the more fancy parameters, just "?limit=200".  I realize this is still marked as a beta endpoint, but I'm wondering if Autodesk is aware of there being an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known issue recently that you will need to specify region in the header. e.g. if your BIM 360 account is EMEA, then set the header when call GET: Project Users. If US, then US.

```
curl --location --request GET 
 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/:projectid/users' \
 --header 'Region: EMEA' \
 --header 'Authorization: Bearer ....'
```

Please let us know if it can work at your side.